# Panache updates not working as documented

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

as I struggle with the behaviour of panache entity updates, I created a demo project to analyze the IMO inconsistent behaviour.

What I have seen so far and what really confuses me:

Updates via io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase#update are working and persisted to db, e.g.

```
@Transactional
public static void updateFirstnameStatic(){
    update("firstname='Paul' where id=1");
}
```

However, querying this exact same entity afterwards

```
Person.findById(1L)
```

returns the initially created Person, not the updated one

Besides, updating an entity by changing its attributes does not work at all, it's not persisted to DB, e.g.

```
@Transactional
public void updateFirstname() {
    firstname = "Paul2";
}
```

This should actually work as it's claimed in the docu https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#most-useful-operations by:
*"note that once persisted, you don't need to explicitly save your entity: all
modifications are automatically persisted on transaction commit."*

What the hell am I doing/getting wrong here?

Complete test project here: https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/blob/jta_tests_panache/src/test/java/org/acme/PersonServiceTest.java

**UPDATE:**

Just got another interesting behaviour after adding `persistAndFlush()` to the second update method which I call from org.acme.PersonServiceTest#testCreatePerson:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends PanacheEntityBase {
...
@Transactional
public void updateFirstname(String firstnameArg) {
    firstname = firstnameArg;
    persistAndFlush();
}
...
}
```

Getting Exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Transaction is not active, consider adding @Transactional to your method to automatically activate one.

    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.flush(TransactionScopedSession.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.flush(SessionLazyDelegator.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.Session_5b93bee577ae2f8d76647de04cfab36afbf52958_Synthetic_ClientProxy.flush(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.flush(AbstractJpaOperations.java:134)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase.persistAndFlush(PanacheEntityBase.java:67)
    at org.acme.entity.Person.updateFirstname(Person.java:30)
    at org.acme.PersonServiceTest.testCreatePerson(PersonServiceTest.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:1083)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:902)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

**UPDATE2:**

Moving the transactional update method to the service and calling this method from org.acme.PersonServiceTest#testCreatePerson also does not update the Person entity.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PersonService {
...

    @Transactional
    public void updatePerson(Person person, String newFirstname){
        person.firstname = newFirstname;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE3 (SOLUTION):**

Update by field changes are only working if the entity is fetched by find in the same transaction, like:

```
@Transactional
public void findAndUpdatePerson(Person personArg, String newFirstname){
    Person person = Person.findById(personArg.id);
    person.firstname = newFirstname;
}
```

However, I don't really get why, as I see no differences in the entity objects after the two lines were executed. AFAI see they are actually identical from their state:
[image]

Could this possibly a bug or is it a bug in my thinking process/understanding?

Answer (score 3):

The update is actually happening, the problem is that when you do the find after the update, the cached value is returned.

If you clear the session after the update, the test will pass:

```
Person.updateFirstnameStatic();         // updates firstname: 'Max' -> 'Paul', updated in DB after this line
Person.getEntityManager().clear();
Person person2 = Person.findById( 1L );  // person2 will contain the updated value
```

Comment: An entity should be persisted into DB (INSERT) on a transaction commit.
If after in out @Transactional annotated method we update an entity it should be persisted. 
And in another method, hence a new call to DB,  in a new Persistent Context, we should read an updated entry from DB.

Comment: If you execute an update query, Hibernate is not going to notice that the entity has changed in the db and when you do the find, it will return the cached value in the session.

Comment: I think the second update doesn't work because the `@Transactional` is ignored, but I need to test this theory.

Comment: @DavideD'Alto thanks for the hint with `Person.getEntityManager().clear()` even though it's hard to believe that I have to add it. About the second update I was encountering an even more interesting situation which I put in my initial post.

Comment: If I were you, I would try to apply the update using a service bean, like we do in the quickstarts

Comment: I did this already see UPDATE2. It also does not update. I wonder if it is maybe generally not working by unit test/@QuarkusTest

Comment: Usually, the approach we use is different. [We would do something like in this example](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/39b77c565014033742085aadbeda64b7c7ba6f78/hibernate-orm-panache-quickstart/src/main/java/org/acme/hibernate/orm/panache/repository/FruitRepositoryResource.java#L67). If you do the find and the update in the same transaction it will work.

Comment: The thing I'm not sure about if it's supposed to work when you do the find outside of a transaction and then the update inside a transaction. I think in Quarkus, every operations should happen in a transaction. But it could also be a bug.

Comment: @DavideD'Alto you are right, update works if do a find directly before in the same transaction. However, this would also mean that passing entities to methods to update them there in another transaction would never work. Could you please check my update (UPDATE3 (SOLUTION)) and let me know what you think? 
I am quite confused that the entity passed to entity (personArg) and the freshly fetched entity are looking identical concerning their state but that update only works with the freshly fetched entity.
Thanks for your thoughts ;)

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure when the entitymanager is created/closed/cleared in the test when one uses `@Transactional`. In your latest update the entities look both managed. But if you do `Panache.getEntityManager().contains(personArg)`, it will return false. Because it's not in the persistence context when the transaction commits, nothing happens.  But I don't know why this is happening, and I will have to debug it to see what's going on (problem is ... I don't have much time at the moment)

Comment: Basically, I think something is wrong with dependency injection (or needs to be better documented), but I'm not sure what is it. Maybe you can create an issue in Quarkus?

Comment: I think what's happening is that it's creating a new session when you  call the second update. This new session doesn't contain the entity and doesn't update it. The `find` add the entity back to the session.

Comment: OK, I will wrap it up in a bug ticket asap and link it here. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Sidenote, in the debugger it says MANAGED for personArg, but `Panache.getEntityManager().contains(personArg)` is false and when I try `Panache.getEntityManager().refresh(personArg);` I get the clear statement in the log (exception): `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed`

Comment: @DavideD'Alto I played around a bit again with the test project (linked in OP). AFAIU atm, the root cause of the issue was that I called the `Person.findById(personArg.id)` in a test method without transaction, while entity is at this place managed. However, when I pass the person entity to a transactional method the entity is not managed anymore, thus updates are not persisted. Weird part about this is IMO, that there is no error. Maybe it's not possible to determine this situation as the entity is not managed (?)